# Node JS MY SQL Manage transaction using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I want to save Object into database in one transaction. Object's have 2 child object and one object of array list, each objects in array list have it's own list of array's:

```
{
  "person": {
    "id": null,
    "personal_no": "555555555555555555"
  },
  "reservation": {
    "id": null,
    "personal_no": null,
    "status_id": null,
    "reservationDetail": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "status_id": null,
        "room_id": 44,
        "start_date": "2017-08-09T18:04:26.938Z",
        "end_date": "2017-08-09T18:04:26.938Z",
        "category_id": 64,
        "reservationPerson": [
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555551"
          },
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555552"
          }
        ],
        "reservationService": [
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555553"
          },
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555554"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": null,
        "status_id": null,
        "room_id": 44,
        "start_date": "2017-08-09T18:04:26.938Z",
        "end_date": "2017-08-09T18:04:26.938Z",
        "category_id": 64,
        "reservationPerson": [
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555556"
          },
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555557"
          }
        ],
        "reservationService": [
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555558"
          },
          {
            "reservation_id": "123",
            "person_id": "5555555555555555559"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

1. I want to do the following steps into one transaction and use
   promise:
   1.1. Save person and return ID.
   1.2. Pass (1.1) returned ID into reservation and return reservation ID.
   1.3. Pass (1.2) returned ID into reservationDetail save and return reservationDetail ID
      1.3.1 Pass (1.3) returned ID into reservationPerson and save.
      1.3.2 Pass (1.3) returned ID into reservationService and save.

This is my code now and i'm stuck, i do not know how to continue.

```
pool.registerReservation = function (reservation) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
            var person = reservation.person;
            connection.beginTransaction(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                connection.query('insert into person  (first_name,last_name,personal_no,email,gender,address,birthdate,phone)values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                    [person.first_name, person.last_name, person.personal_no, person.email, person.gender, person.address, person.birthdate, person.phone],
                    function (error, results, fields) {
                        if (error) {
                            if (error.code != 'ER_DUP_ENTRY') {
                                return connection.rollback(function () {
                                    console.log("person", error.code);
                                    reject(error);
                                });
                            }

                        }
                        connection.query('insert into reservation (create_date,person_no,status_id)values(current_timestamp,?,1)', [person.personal_no], function (error, results, fields) {
                            if (error) {
                                return connection.rollback(function () {
                                    console.log("reservation", error);
                                    reject(error);
                                });
                            }
                            var reservID = results.insertId;
                            var reservDetails = reservation.reservation.reservationDetail;

                            reservDetails.map(data => {

                                connection.query('insert into reservation_detail (reservation_id,create_date,room_id,status_id,start_date,end_date,payment_type,adult,child,additional_bed,payment_status)values(?,current_timestamp,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                                    [reservID, data.room_id, data.status_id, data.start_date, data.end_date,
                                        data.payment_type, data.adult, data.child, data.additional_bed, data.payment_status],
                                    function (error, results, fields) {
                                        if (error) {
                                            return connection.rollback(function () {
                                                console.log("reservation_detail", error);
                                                reject(error);
                                            });
                                        }
                                        data.id = results.insertId;
                                        var id = results.insertId;

                                        data.reservationPerson.map(person => {
                                            connection.query('insert into reservation_person(reservation_id,person_id)values(?,?)',
                                                [id, person.person_id],
                                                function (error, results, fields) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        return connection.rollback(function () {
                                                            console.log("person", error.code);
                                                            reject(error);
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        });
                                        data.reservationService.map(service => {
                                            connection.query('insert into reservation_service (reservation_id, service_id,frequency, additional_comment)values (?,?,?,?)',
                                                [id, service.service_id, service.frequency, service.additional_comment],
                                                function (error, results, fields) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        return connection.rollback(function () {
                                                            console.log("service", error);
                                                            reject(error);
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                });
                                        });
                                    });
                            });

                            connection.commit(function (err) {
                                console.log("commit");
                                if (err) {
                                    return connection.rollback(function () {
                                        console.log(err);
                                        reject(err);
                                    });
                                }
                                resolve("OK");
                            });
                        });
                    });
            });
        });
    });
}
```